# How to remove white space from json object key in retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, android-lifecycle

I am having a string which has white space. How to remove the white space in retrofit. In the below response, you can see "Poster" and "Poster " (There is whitespace)

Where exactly need to handle this json key to remove the whitespace in retrofit?

```
{
    "movies": [{
        "Title": "TheAvengers ",
        "Year": "2012 ",
        "Rated": "PG-13 ",
        "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi ",
        "Actors": "Robert Downey Jr., Chris Evans, Mark Ruffalo, Chris Hemsworth ",
        "Plot": "Earth's mightiest heroes must come together and learn to fight as a team if they are going to stop the mischievous Loki and his alien army from enslaving humanity. ",
        "Language": "English, Russian, Hindi ",
        "Country": "USA ",
        "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDYxNjQyMjAtNTdiOS00NGYwLWFmNTAtNThmYjU5ZGI2YTI1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg ",
        "Released": "04 May 2012 ",
        "Runtime": "143 min ",
        "Director": "Joss Whedon ",
        "Writer": "Joss Whedon (screenplay), Zak Penn (story), Joss Whedon (story) ",
        "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 38 wins \u0026 79 nominations. "
    }, {
        "Title": "Sleepless ",
        "Year": "2017 ",
        "Rated": "R ",
        "Released": "13Jan 2017 ",
        "Runtime": "95 min ",
        "Genre": "Action, Crime, Thriller ",
        "Director": "Baran bo Odar ",
        "Writer": "Andrea Berloff (screenplay by), Frédéric Jardin (based on the film    Nuit blanche written by), Nicolas Saada (based on the film Nuit blanche written by), Olivier Douyère (based on the film    Nuit blanche   written by)",
        "Actors": "Jamie Foxx, Michelle Monaghan, Scoot McNairy, Dermot Mulroney ",
        "Plot": "A cop with a connection to the criminal underworld scours a nightclub in search of his kidnapped son. ",
        "Language": "English ",
        "Country": "USA ",
        "Awards": "1 nomination. ",
        "Poster ": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjEwMDAyOTM4OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzc4MjMyMDI@._V1_SX300.jpg "
    }]}
```

Below is the code what I done and I am hanged where I need to remove the whitespace for Poster.

**Pojo Class:**

```
public class Movies implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("Title")
    private String Title;
    @SerializedName("Year")
    private String Year;
    @SerializedName("Rated")
    private String Rated;
    @SerializedName("Released")
    private String Released;
    @SerializedName("Runtime")
    private String Runtime;
    @SerializedName("Genre")
    private String Genre;
    @SerializedName("Director")
    private String Director;
    @SerializedName("Writer")
    private String Writer;
    @SerializedName("Actors")
    private String Actors;
    @SerializedName("Plot")
    private String Plot;
    @SerializedName("Language")
    private String Language;
    @SerializedName("Country")
    private String Country;
    @SerializedName("Awards")
    private String Awards;
    @SerializedName("Poster")
    private String Poster;


    // Getter Methods

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return Year;
    }

    public String getRated() {
        return Rated;
    }

    public String getReleased() {
        return Released;
    }

    public String getRuntime() {
        return Runtime;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return Genre;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return Director;
    }

    public String getWriter() {
        return Writer;
    }

    public String getActors() {
        return Actors;
    }

    public String getPlot() {
        return Plot;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return Language;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
    }

    public String getAwards() {
        return Awards;
    }

    public String getPoster() {
        return Poster == null ? Uri.parse("R.drawable.ic_launcher_background").toString() : Poster;
    }

    // Setter Methods

    public void setTitle(String Title) {
        this.Title = Title;
    }

    public void setYear(String Year) {
        this.Year = Year;
    }

    public void setRated(String Rated) {
        this.Rated = Rated;
    }

    public void setReleased(String Released) {
        this.Released = Released;
    }

    public void setRuntime(String Runtime) {
        this.Runtime = Runtime;
    }

    public void setGenre(String Genre) {
        this.Genre = Genre;
    }

    public void setDirector(String Director) {
        this.Director = Director;
    }

    public void setWriter(String Writer) {
        this.Writer = Writer;
    }

    public void setActors(String Actors) {
        this.Actors = Actors;
    }

    public void setPlot(String Plot) {
        this.Plot = Plot;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String Language) {
        this.Language = Language;
    }

    public void setCountry(String Country) {
        this.Country = Country;
    }

    public void setAwards(String Awards) {
        this.Awards = Awards;
    }

    public void setPoster(String Poster) {
        this.Poster = Poster;
    }
}
```

MovieResponse:

```
public class MovieResponse implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("movies")
    private List<Movies> movies;

    public List<Movies> getMovies() {
        return movies;
    }

    public void setMovies(List<Movies> movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
    }
}
```

RetrofitService:

```
 public class RetrofitService {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com/bins/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    public static <S> S cteateService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

MoviesRepository: (Here is where I am handling the response)

```
    public class MoviesRepository {
        private static MoviesRepository moviesRepository;
        private MovieApiInterface newsApi;
        public static Application application;

        public static MoviesRepository getInstance() {
            if (moviesRepository == null) {
                moviesRepository = new MoviesRepository(application);
            }
            return moviesRepository;
        }
  public MoviesRepository(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
        newsApi = RetrofitService.cteateService(MovieApiInterface.class);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> getMovieUpdates() {
        final MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> moviesData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        newsApi.getMovieDetails().enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson mGson = builder.create();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if(response.body()!=null) {
                        moviesData.setValue(response.body());
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("RETROFIT RESPONSE", "Failure"+call.toString());
                Log.i("RETROFIT RESPONSE", "Failure"+t);
               // moviesData.setValue(null);

            }
        });
        return moviesData;
    }



      public interface MovieApiInterface {
        @GET("9xqev")
        Call<MovieResponse> getMovieDetails();
    }
```

**I am clueless where I need to check by converting from gson.FromJson to change the poster key string.** which has whitespace.

I have used MVVM where all datas I am getting except poster which has whitespace.

```
public class MoviesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> mutableLiveData;
    private MoviesRepository moviesRepository;

    public MoviesViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        moviesRepository = new MoviesRepository(application);
    }

    public void init() {
        if (mutableLiveData != null) {
            return;
        }
        moviesRepository = MoviesRepository.getInstance();
        mutableLiveData = moviesRepository.getMovieUpdates();
    }

    public MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> getNewsRepository() {
        return moviesRepository.getMovieUpdates();
    }
}
```

Other ways I tried are:
 Failed Case 1 :
 I am not able to place two Poster with whitespace in Serializable

```
@SerializedName("Poster")
    private String Poster;

@SerializedName("Poster ") // with whitespace.
    private String Poster;
```

Failed Case 2: (Used trim but this is reflecting only for values but not for key)

```
public String getPoster() {
        return Poster == null ? Uri.parse("R.drawable.ic_launcher_background").toString() : Poster.trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me simplify from @JoopEggen 's answer and comments.

When you apply two fields

```
 @SerializedName(value="Poster", alternate={"Poster ", "Pöster"})
  String poster;
```

It throws "You can't declare multiple JSON fields named Poster"

So what's the **solution** is,

```
//assign a dummy json field as images and replace with poster

@SerializedName(value = "Images", alternate = {"Poster"}) //no whitespace
    private String Images;


@SerializedName("Poster ") //with white space
    private String Poster;
```

Handle this two images in adapter from getter setter.

```
   String poster= movies.get(position).getPoster(); //Poster with whitespace
    String image = movies.get(position).getImages(); //Poster without whitespace
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@SerializedName(value="Poster", alternate={"Poster ", "Pöster"})
String poster;
```

---

***This seems not to work, see comment, for alternates that trimmed give the same name.***

Comment: I used this but I am getting crash that, Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class movie..demo.DataModel.Movies declares multiple JSON fields named Poster

Comment: Just with `alternate="Poster "`? So it seems not to work internally. Sorry.

Comment: Is there any other alternative solution for this. I tried many ways but still I couldn't find and hanged into this. @Joop Eggen

Comment: @Star sorry, seems some converter has to be chained, simple doing a textual trim on the keys. No idea with retrofit.

Comment: Okay, no problem. @Joop

Answer (score 1):

Try using the benefits of getter function

```
public String getTitle() {
        return Title.trim();
    }
```

as same with others as well. try to use this, if this will not help let m know in the comment, we'll find another solution

Comment: I tried this but this fixes only for values but not for key.

Comment: Also i tried this way too.  public String getPoster() {
        return Poster == null ? Uri.parse("R.drawable.ic_launcher_background").toString() : Poster.trim();
    }

Comment: why do you need it to trim keys, values are useful not keys. Is there anything specific?

Comment: I used Title.trim but I am getting error as Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference

Comment: No. Actually I need to acces the url  from the Poster but it has two different Poster that's the problem.

Comment: what did you mean by that, is Movie().getPoster() not returning you the URL

Comment: it's actually a string. Let me simplify and say. {
 "movies": [{
  "Title": "Avengers:Age of Ultron ",
  "Year": "2015 ",
 }, {
  "Title": "TheAvengers ",
  "Year": "2012 ",
  "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDYxNjQyMjAtNTdiOS00NGYwLWFmNTAtNThmYjU5ZGI2YTI1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg ",
 }, {
  "Title": "Sleepless ",
  "Year": "2017 ",
  "Poster ": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjEwMDAyOTM4OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzc4MjMyMDI@._V1_SX300.jpg "
 }]}

Comment: In the above json structure, first contains no poster field, second contains "Poster" field and third contains "Poster " fields. Third has white space but second and third Poster has url. But I can use only one Poster field.

Comment: I tried @Joop's solution but I am not able to use two fields at a time @SerializedName(value="Poster", alternate={"Poster ", "Poster"})

Comment: what do you mean by two fields at a time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195929/discussion-between-star-and-lakhwinder-singh).

Answer (score 1):

use this code into your project :

```
String strRemoveSpace= getPoster().toString().replaceAll("\\s", ""); // using built in method  
System.out.println(strRemoveSpace);
```